# Extracting a number from a string in a XSLT file

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

Is there a way to extract a number from a string after a set of characters.

Our software uses XSLT files to convert emails into XML files.  In the Subject line of an email there can be a reference to an already opened Incident/Service Request/Task.

For example - the Subject of an email could be:

```
RE: SR#51417: D_SATTER-NOV60LKA-I_G-A0201244
```

I want to extract the Service Request Number 51417 from the Subject.
The number will always be after the String "SR#".  "SR#" could be written as "sr#", "Sr#" or "sR#".

I was trying to use the RegEx functions in XSLT but can't get it to work.

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Update
I am trying the solution provided by cyclexx.  This is the Code that I have put in my XSLT File:

`<xsl:when test="contains($subject, 'SR#')">
<xsl:element name="Field">
    <xsl:attribute name="Name">
        <xsl:text>a_eco_parentObjectType</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="'ServiceReq'"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="Field">
    <xsl:attribute name="Name">
        <xsl:text>a_eco_parentObjectID</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:analyze-string select ="$subject" regex="\s*[Ss][Rr]#([0-9]+)\s*">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <SR>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"></xsl:value-of>
            </SR>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:element>`

The variable $subject contains the Subject line of the Email file that is being processed.  The output file just contains:

ServiceReq

and I have an error message: :Error in loading Hierarchical Object XSLT file(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution :)

```html
<emails>
  <email>
    <subject>RE: SR#51417: D_SATTER-NOV60LKA-I_G-A0201244</subject>
  </email>
  <email>
    <subject>RE: Sr#565465: D_SATTER-NOV60LKA-I_G-A0201244</subject>
  </email>
</emails>


<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:template match="subject">

    <xsl:variable name="v" select="." />

    <xsl:analyze-string select="$v" regex="\s*[Ss][Rr]#([0-9]+)\s*">

      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <SR>
          <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)" />
        </SR>
      </xsl:matching-substring>

      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <subject>
          <xsl:value-of select="$v"/>
        </subject>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>

    </xsl:analyze-string>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried your solution but I am having a problem getting it to work.

Comment: <xsl:when test="contains($subject, 'SR#')">
 <xsl:element name="Field">
  <xsl:attribute name="Name">
   <xsl:text>a_eco_parentObjectType</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="'ServiceReq'"/>
 </xsl:element>
 <xsl:element name="Field">
  <xsl:attribute name="Name">
  <xsl:text>a_eco_parentObjectID</xsl:text>
 </xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:analyze-string select ="$subject" regex="\s*[Ss][Rr]#([0-9]+)\s*">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
   <SR>
    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
   </SR>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:element></xsl:when>

Comment: @LondonKiwi Can you make a XML example ?

Comment: @LondonKiwi, don't tell us you are having a problem, tell us the symptoms. Without knowing the symptoms, my first guess would be that you are trying to run this with an XSLT 1.0 processor. XSLT 1.0 was superseded by 2.0 ten years ago and people are starting to assume that's what you are using unless you tell us otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelKay- sorry - i was trying to paste in an example but it seems I am limited to a certain number of characters and couldn't get the formatting to work.  Each time I try to use the return key it just closes the comments box.

Comment: @LondonKiwi We dont need all the file, only an usefull part

Comment: I have just found out that the software only supports some XSLT 2.0 functions but helpfully doesn't detail which ones.